# Reshape String, inserting "\n" at every N characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Using JavaScript functions, I was trying to insert a breakline on a string at every N characters provided by the user.

Just like this: `function("blabla", 3) would output "bla\nbla\n".`

I searched a lot of answers and ended up with a regex to do that, the only problem is, I need the user's input on the matter, so I need to stuck a variable on this regex.

Here's the code:

```
function reshapeString(string, num) {
    var regex = new RegExp("/(.{" + num + "})/g");
    return string.replace(regex,"$1\n");
}

reshapeString("blablabla", 3);
```

This is currently not working. I tried to escape the '/' characters, but I'm screwing up at some point and I don't know where.

What am I missing? Is there any other way to solve the problem of reshaping this string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a string for the regexp constructor, without `/`, and you can omit the group by using `$&` for the found string.

```js
function reshapeString(string, num) {
    var regex = new RegExp(".{" + num + "}", "g");
    return string.replace(regex,"$&\n");
}

console.log(reshapeString("blablabla", 3));
```

Comment: What if the reshapeString("abc ab abc") has like arguments? I'm trying to get output like this: - abc \n ab \n abc

Comment: @NirmalPatel, the question and answer uses same length for the parts for breaking, not variable part lengths.

Answer (score 3):

How about a one-liner?

```
const reshapeString = (str,N) => str.split('').reduce((o,c,i) => o+(!i || i%N?'':'\n')+c, '')
```

#### Explanation:

- So first thing we do is split the string into a character array
- Now we use a [***`reduce()`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) statement to go through each element and reduce to a single value (*ie. the final string you're looking for!*)
- Now `i%N` should give a non-zero (*ie. **a truthy** value*) when the *index* is not a multiple of `N`, so we just add the current character to out accumulator variable `o`.
- If `i%N` is in fact `0` (*then it's **falsey** in value*), and we append:

  - `o` (*the string so far*) +
  - `\n` (*the appended character at the `N`'th interval*)
  - `c` (*the current character*)
- ***Note***: We also have a `!i` check, that's for ignoring the first char since, that may be considered un-intended behavior

### Benchmarking

Regex construction and replace also requires string re-construction and creating an FSA to follow. Which for strings smaller than 1000 should be slower

#### Test:

```
(_ => {
    const reshapeString_AP = (str,N) => str.split('').reduce((o,c,i) => o+(!i || i%N?'':'\n')+c, '')
    function reshapeString_Nina(string, num) {
        var regex = new RegExp(".{" + num + "}", "g");
        return string.replace(regex,"$&\n");
    }

    const payload = 'a'.repeat(100)
    console.time('AP');
    reshapeString_AP(payload, 4)
    console.timeEnd('AP');
    console.time('Nina');
    reshapeString_Nina(payload, 4)
    console.timeEnd('Nina');
})()
```

#### Results (3 runs):

```
AP: 0.080078125ms
Nina: 0.13916015625ms
---
AP: 0.057861328125ms
Nina: 0.119140625ms
---
AP: 0.070068359375ms
Nina: 0.116943359375ms
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer (and what I was in the middle of typing). :D

Comment: You were just faster at typing than I was able to. Glad to see someone else thinking like this instead of silly RegEx.

Comment: Care to walk me through this? I'm a real begginer.

Comment: Well, testing this on a js environment, it seems the first character it's separated from the rest, like: "blablabla" turns into "b\nlab\nlab\nla"

Comment: Added an ignore for the first char, cuz 0 is technically a multiple of `N`

Comment: Because the first character will have an index of 0. Doesn't seem to work in all browsers, either. Nice though.

Comment: Well, now is ignoring the first character allright, but still un-intended behavior is happening. "blablabla" turns into "blab\nlab\nla". The first division is always getting +one char.

Comment: @Platiplus I would recommend you accept Nina's answer below, since it answers your actual question. I would expect hers to be faster too, since regex operates at a low level, compared to iterating through an array with an if statement and building a string.

Comment: The sequencing of the operations was wrong, I've corrected it. @Platiplus.

Comment: @Toby you're wrong, regex is way slower for probably most cases OP is going to run. It only outperforms this approach after about `1,000` character strings

Comment: Put a strip or a substring to remove the leading newline.

Comment: @AP - where did OP say strings would be less than 1000 characters? Why would he be inserting newlines into small sentences? Your answer is not helpful - you ignored his original issue completely and recommended your preferred approach, which had bugs in it, and has limitations you haven't made clear in your answer. Adding bench testing is interesting, but only proves that, indeed, your answer has potential pitfalls. OP still doesn't have a working solution from you.

Comment: @Toby How does this answer not tackle: _"Is there any other way to solve the problem of reshaping this string?"_ Fair point regarding string length, but this solution does offer advantages in certain conditions, and would definitely be considered a valid approach regardless of string length?

Comment: @AP Fair enough on suggesting the other way. As I have said, it's a very neat solution, but it still wasn't working when I wrote my comment, and I still think it is better for SO to have a regex fix to a regex bug and maybe then a suggestion on another approach. It's not personal!

Answer (score 1):

public static String reshape(int n, String str){

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    char[] c = str.replaceAll(" " , "").toCharArray();
        int count =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if(count != n){
                sb.append(c[i]);
                count++;
             }else {
                count = 1;
                sb.append("\n").append(c[i]);
            }
        }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable so whatever you do you have to create a new string. It's best to start creating it in the first place.

```js
var newLineForEach = (n,s) => s && `${s.slice(0,n)}\n${newLineForEach(n,s.slice(n))}`,
    result = newLineForEach(3,"blablabla");
console.log(result);
```

So my tests show that this is by far the fastest. 100K iterations resulted Nina's 1260msec, AP's 103msec and Redu's 33msec. The accepted answer is very inefficient.